# Buttons don't work in new activity crated from service foreground window

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, foreground-service

I have a foreground Service with a button without any activities (initial was closed). When I click button the new activity window is created. The problem is that all buttons in new activity don't work

In foreground service I do:

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    if (!moving) {
        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, Mmap_activity::class.java)
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT))
    }
}
```

In Manifest new activity declared:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Mmap_activity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

activity_mmap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Mmap_activity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/leftBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80"
        android:orientation="vertical" />



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottomBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mapexitButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Enter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomBorder"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/leftBorder"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck"
        tools:visibility="visible" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Mmap_activity.kt:

```
class Mmap_activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMmapBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mmap)
        binding = ActivityMmapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.mapexitButton.setOnClickListener{
            println("button pressed")
        }

    }

}
```

How to repair button in new activity? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was here.

```
binding = ActivityMmapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```